# Getting "Name or service not known" error on every CLI opsworks command

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-opsworks, aws-cli

I'm trying to perform a deployment from the AWS CLI.
Unfortunately, the following error occurs.
Moreover, trying pretty much any command from `opsworks` causes the same reaction.
I have my credentials specified in `~/.aws/credentials` (as the trace shows) and have run `aws configure` as well.

Any ideas what could be causing that?

My setup: `aws-cli/1.7.0 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-37-generic`

Following is the output from another command (the errors are the same):

```
$ aws opsworks describe-deployments --debug
2015-01-13 08:50:01,763 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - CLI version: aws-cli/1.7.0 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-37-generic, botocore version: 0.81.0
2015-01-13 08:50:01,763 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function add_scalar_parsers at 0x7f824aeffed8>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,763 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event session-initialized: calling handler <function inject_assume_role_provider at 0x7f824af3af50>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,763 - MainThread - botocore.service - DEBUG - Creating service object for: opsworks
2015-01-13 08:50:01,788 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.opsworks: calling handler <function register_retries_for_service at 0x7f824b3a85f0>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,790 - MainThread - botocore.handlers - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: opsworks
2015-01-13 08:50:01,790 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.opsworks: calling handler <function signature_overrides at 0x7f824b3a8758>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,790 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.opsworks: calling handler <function register_retries_for_service at 0x7f824b3a85f0>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,791 - MainThread - botocore.handlers - DEBUG - Registering retry handlers for service: opsworks
2015-01-13 08:50:01,791 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event service-data-loaded.opsworks: calling handler <function signature_overrides at 0x7f824b3a8758>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,791 - MainThread - botocore.service - DEBUG - Creating operation objects for: Service(opsworks)
2015-01-13 08:50:01,795 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.opsworks: calling handler <function inject_commands at 0x7f824af05320>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,795 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-command-table.opsworks: calling handler <function add_waiters at 0x7f824af4bcf8>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,796 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - OrderedDict([(u'stack-id', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x7f824a99bb50>), (u'app-id', <awscli.arguments.CLIArgument object at 0x7f824a99bb90>), (u'deployment-ids', <awscli.arguments.ListArgument object at 0x7f824a99bbd0>)])
2015-01-13 08:50:01,796 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.opsworks.describe-deployments: calling handler <function add_streaming_output_arg at 0x7f824b021050>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,797 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.opsworks.describe-deployments: calling handler <function _rename_arg at 0x7f824ac1f320>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,797 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.opsworks.describe-deployments: calling handler <function add_cli_input_json at 0x7f824af3a230>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,797 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.opsworks.describe-deployments: calling handler <function unify_paging_params at 0x7f824b021e60>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,797 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event building-argument-table.opsworks.describe-deployments: calling handler <function add_generate_skeleton at 0x7f824af3a758>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,797 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.opsworks.describe-deployments: calling handler <bound method CliInputJSONArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x7f824a99bc50>>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,797 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event before-building-argument-table-parser.opsworks.describe-deployments: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.override_required_args of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x7f824a99bc90>>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,798 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.opsworks.describe-deployments.stack-id: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x7f824b060cf8>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,798 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.opsworks.describe-deployments.app-id: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x7f824b060cf8>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,798 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.opsworks.describe-deployments.deployment-ids: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x7f824b060cf8>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,798 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.opsworks.describe-deployments.cli-input-json: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x7f824b060cf8>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,798 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event load-cli-arg.opsworks.describe-deployments.generate-cli-skeleton: calling handler <function uri_param at 0x7f824b060cf8>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,799 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.opsworks.describe-deployments: calling handler <bound method GenerateCliSkeletonArgument.generate_json_skeleton of <awscli.customizations.generatecliskeleton.GenerateCliSkeletonArgument object at 0x7f824a99bc90>>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,799 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event calling-command.opsworks.describe-deployments: calling handler <bound method CliInputJSONArgument.add_to_call_parameters of <awscli.customizations.cliinputjson.CliInputJSONArgument object at 0x7f824a99bc50>>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,799 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: env
2015-01-13 08:50:01,799 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2015-01-13 08:50:01,799 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - DEBUG - Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2015-01-13 08:50:01,799 - MainThread - botocore.credentials - INFO - Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2015-01-13 08:50:01,801 - MainThread - botocore.operation - DEBUG - Operation:DescribeDeployments called with kwargs: {}
2015-01-13 08:50:01,801 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Making request for <botocore.model.OperationModel object at 0x7f824a9fed50> (verify_ssl=True) with params: {'query_string': '', 'headers': {'Content-Type': u'application/x-amz-json-1.1', 'X-Amz-Target': u'OpsWorks_20130218.DescribeDeployments'}, 'url_path': '/', 'body': '{}', 'method': u'POST'}
2015-01-13 08:50:01,802 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2015-01-13 08:50:01,802 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
host:opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-cli/1.7.0 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-37-generic
x-amz-date:20150113T075001Z
x-amz-target:OpsWorks_20130218.DescribeDeployments

content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
44136fa355b3678a1146ad16f7e8649e94fb4fc21fe77e8310c060f61caaff8a
2015-01-13 08:50:01,802 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20150113T075001Z
20150113/eu-west-1/opsworks/aws4_request
9aa9deace780bfb83917e28657ce9474dba70ebf07d5c9a58511dfb114e1c2ac
2015-01-13 08:50:01,802 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
f68a8efefe97f7dedccbe05d614aea1e8d5fd3346d93ffe6be15f15dcfc64a33
2015-01-13 08:50:01,806 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [POST]>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,806 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (1): opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
2015-01-13 08:50:01,813 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Exception received when sending HTTP request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 192, in _get_response
    proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 356, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
2015-01-13 08:50:01,814 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.opsworks.DescribeDeployments: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7f824a9fe0d0>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,814 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - retry needed, retryable exception caught: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 262, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 310, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 219, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 352, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
2015-01-13 08:50:01,814 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - Retry needed, action of: 0.151088018404
2015-01-13 08:50:01,814 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Response received to retry, sleeping for 0.151088018404 seconds
2015-01-13 08:50:01,966 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2015-01-13 08:50:01,967 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
host:opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-cli/1.7.0 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-37-generic
x-amz-date:20150113T075001Z
x-amz-target:OpsWorks_20130218.DescribeDeployments

content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
44136fa355b3678a1146ad16f7e8649e94fb4fc21fe77e8310c060f61caaff8a
2015-01-13 08:50:01,967 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20150113T075001Z
20150113/eu-west-1/opsworks/aws4_request
9aa9deace780bfb83917e28657ce9474dba70ebf07d5c9a58511dfb114e1c2ac
2015-01-13 08:50:01,967 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
f68a8efefe97f7dedccbe05d614aea1e8d5fd3346d93ffe6be15f15dcfc64a33
2015-01-13 08:50:01,968 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [POST]>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,968 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (2): opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
2015-01-13 08:50:01,975 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Exception received when sending HTTP request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 192, in _get_response
    proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 356, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
2015-01-13 08:50:01,975 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.opsworks.DescribeDeployments: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7f824a9fe0d0>
2015-01-13 08:50:01,975 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - retry needed, retryable exception caught: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 262, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 310, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 219, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 352, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
2015-01-13 08:50:01,975 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - Retry needed, action of: 1.61889080118
2015-01-13 08:50:01,976 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Response received to retry, sleeping for 1.61889080118 seconds
2015-01-13 08:50:03,595 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2015-01-13 08:50:03,595 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
host:opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-cli/1.7.0 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-37-generic
x-amz-date:20150113T075003Z
x-amz-target:OpsWorks_20130218.DescribeDeployments

content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
44136fa355b3678a1146ad16f7e8649e94fb4fc21fe77e8310c060f61caaff8a
2015-01-13 08:50:03,595 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20150113T075003Z
20150113/eu-west-1/opsworks/aws4_request
999feead1270c4d7f28d736d2eb03c42dea61beec48036febc320595069394d0
2015-01-13 08:50:03,596 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
55b489808ea12c05363d49c3783884768cfba3142470d0c2de73666b53015d34
2015-01-13 08:50:03,596 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [POST]>
2015-01-13 08:50:03,596 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (3): opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
2015-01-13 08:50:03,602 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Exception received when sending HTTP request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 192, in _get_response
    proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 356, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
2015-01-13 08:50:03,602 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.opsworks.DescribeDeployments: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7f824a9fe0d0>
2015-01-13 08:50:03,602 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - retry needed, retryable exception caught: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 262, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 310, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 219, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 352, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
2015-01-13 08:50:03,602 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - Retry needed, action of: 0.465219741591
2015-01-13 08:50:03,602 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Response received to retry, sleeping for 0.465219741591 seconds
2015-01-13 08:50:04,069 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2015-01-13 08:50:04,069 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
host:opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-cli/1.7.0 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-37-generic
x-amz-date:20150113T075004Z
x-amz-target:OpsWorks_20130218.DescribeDeployments

content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
44136fa355b3678a1146ad16f7e8649e94fb4fc21fe77e8310c060f61caaff8a
2015-01-13 08:50:04,070 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20150113T075004Z
20150113/eu-west-1/opsworks/aws4_request
74772206c4c44c97dff331e5fb82b7c5f6f9efbd4dca2d30642b716adbf3b6e6
2015-01-13 08:50:04,070 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
ec00007f3d0e4419d461376326bd93cf74626f007a6ecf7ca38dc8773fb5be76
2015-01-13 08:50:04,071 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [POST]>
2015-01-13 08:50:04,071 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (4): opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
2015-01-13 08:50:04,076 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Exception received when sending HTTP request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 192, in _get_response
    proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 356, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
2015-01-13 08:50:04,077 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.opsworks.DescribeDeployments: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7f824a9fe0d0>
2015-01-13 08:50:04,077 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - retry needed, retryable exception caught: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 262, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 310, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 219, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 352, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
2015-01-13 08:50:04,078 - MainThread - botocore.retryhandler - DEBUG - Retry needed, action of: 3.97346299718
2015-01-13 08:50:04,078 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Response received to retry, sleeping for 3.97346299718 seconds
2015-01-13 08:50:08,056 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Calculating signature using v4 auth.
2015-01-13 08:50:08,057 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - CanonicalRequest:
POST
/

content-type:application/x-amz-json-1.1
host:opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
user-agent:aws-cli/1.7.0 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-37-generic
x-amz-date:20150113T075008Z
x-amz-target:OpsWorks_20130218.DescribeDeployments

content-type;host;user-agent;x-amz-date;x-amz-target
44136fa355b3678a1146ad16f7e8649e94fb4fc21fe77e8310c060f61caaff8a
2015-01-13 08:50:08,057 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - StringToSign:
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20150113T075008Z
20150113/eu-west-1/opsworks/aws4_request
750fd5cc579795b85f1e88156955d7a6da6b9b6f1b9619b24693124e1d958bd0
2015-01-13 08:50:08,058 - MainThread - botocore.auth - DEBUG - Signature:
983616ec65934aff0e99c9e75601b29cc94ab9ca65a0b3a26302545cb3db2bfa
2015-01-13 08:50:08,059 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Sending http request: <PreparedRequest [POST]>
2015-01-13 08:50:08,059 - MainThread - botocore.vendored.requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool - INFO - Starting new HTTPS connection (5): opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com
2015-01-13 08:50:08,066 - MainThread - botocore.endpoint - DEBUG - Exception received when sending HTTP request.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 192, in _get_response
    proxies=self.proxies, timeout=self.timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/sessions.py", line 464, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/vendored/requests/adapters.py", line 356, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e)
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
2015-01-13 08:50:08,066 - MainThread - botocore.hooks - DEBUG - Event needs-retry.opsworks.DescribeDeployments: calling handler <botocore.retryhandler.RetryHandler object at 0x7f824a9fe0d0>
2015-01-13 08:50:08,067 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exception caught in main()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 197, in main
    return command_table[parsed_args.command](remaining, parsed_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 357, in __call__
    return command_table[parsed_args.operation](remaining, parsed_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 492, in __call__
    self._operation_object, call_parameters, parsed_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/awscli/clidriver.py", line 597, in invoke
    **parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/operation.py", line 90, in call
    response = endpoint.make_request(self.model, request_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 109, in make_request
    return self._send_request(prepared_request, operation_model)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 172, in _send_request
    response, exception):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/endpoint.py", line 213, in _needs_retry
    caught_exception=caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 226, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 209, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 180, in __call__
    if self._checker(attempts, response, caught_exception):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 247, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 270, in _should_retry
    return self._checker(attempt_number, response, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 310, in __call__
    caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 219, in __call__
    return self._check_caught_exception(attempt_number, caught_exception)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/retryhandler.py", line 352, in _check_caught_exception
    raise caught_exception
ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
2015-01-13 08:50:08,068 - MainThread - awscli.clidriver - DEBUG - Exiting with rc 255

HTTPSConnectionPool(host='opsworks.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to use the `us-east-1` region when calling Opsworks commands.  You can change this value via the `--region` argument or by setting a different default region when you run `aws configure`.  From the [FAQ](http://aws.amazon.com/opsworks/faqs/):

> You can configure OpsWorks instances to be launched in any AWS region except GovCloud. OpsWorks itself runs in US East (Northern Virginia) and provides access to all of your OpsWorks applications, no matter where they’re running.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I didn't infer that connection.

Comment: By the way, I seem to be getting a sensible error message in `aws 1.2.6` (i.e. that opsworks only works in `us-east-1`), but that's not the case in `1.7.0`. Regression or intended action?

Comment: Something we're looking to fix.  Currently being tracked in: https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/339